# long running process behind .NET service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service

I would like advice from the architecturally minded on the best framework or method for the following:

server: a windows service in .NET

client: any mainstream language, a combination of .NET app/web app, and also some clients that are Ruby on Linux.

One idea I had was to have the Windows Service expose itself as a Web Service, and supply web service methods for starting a job, canceling the job, getting status, and getting results.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately the service needs a host. You can use a simple windows service or a hosting application. IIS is designed to do this. I would seriously consider hosting your service (web service or other protocols) inside an IIS hosted process. IIS has management support and the new [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx) technology builds on this to give better management and scaling capability.

As the service itself I'd consider using on open web type architecture, such as [REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx) to give you compatibility with as many different platforms.

Are your long running processes a workflow? If so you can leverage .net WF to do for you and WF in .net 4 is completely IIS hosted already.

Comment: REST is fine, but a basic profile Web Service can give you more facilities for client proxy generation. Or can you have this proxy in a REST server ?

Comment: With WCF its easy I think, but maybe with technologies its harder. However there will be libraries that will work with HTTP.